# Change Month Name in MySQL date_format?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I change the month name from like `October` (English) to `Oktober` (Danish) after I made my SQL query.

Query:
`SELECT id, name, date_format(timestamp, '%M %e, %Y %l:%i %p') real_timestamp FROM comments WHERE active='yes'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `str_replace` function

```
$result = str_replace("October", "Oktober", $result);
```

see [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)